# Merge 2 Functions in FPDF

Tags: php, html, pdf, fpdf

I am using [**FPDF**](http://fpdf.org/) in printing lists. Currently, I am using the [WriteHTML](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script42.php) script by Clément Lavoillotte so I can use HTML tags in my table. However, I also want to wrap long texts to fit in a cell. I'm thinking of merging [Table with MultiCells](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script3.php) script by Olivier with what I have now but I can't make it work.

Here's one of the PDF's I'm having problem with.

[image]

How can I make the long texts fit on the cell where it's in?

Here's my code:

```
private function generate_picklist($bu_id,$ids,$isdebug=false){
    if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in()) { echo  'access denied'; exit; }
    ob_start();
    //Create PDF
    require('application/libraries/htmltopdf/WriteHTML.php');

//SAVE THE PICKLIST NUMBER ON ITEMS
//GENERATE PICKLIST NUMBER
$len = "10";
$pick_list_no = '';
$pick_list_no = $code=sprintf("%0".$len."d", mt_rand(1, str_pad("", $len,"9")));

    $get_pick_list = $this->PrintModel->get_pick_list($bu_id, $ids, $pick_list_no);

    $pdf=new PDF_HTML();

    $pdf->AliasNbPages();
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 15);
    $pdf->PageNo();
    $pdf->addPage('L');

    $this->pdf_header($pdf,$bu_id,'Pick List','Date:  '.date("Y/m/d"), '', 'PL #: '.$get_pick_list[0]['picklist_no']);

    $rc_y = 20; 

    $pdf->SetXY(10,$rc_y + 40);

    $header = array(array('name'=>'Date Received','width'=>45),
                    array('name'=>'Customer Name','width'=>45),
        array('name'=>'Vendor','width'=>30),
                    array('name'=>'Item','width'=>45),
                    array('name'=>'Quantity','width'=>25),
                    array('name'=>'Price','width'=>30),
        array('name'=>'Shelf #','width'=>30),
    );
    $row_ht = 7;

    // Header
    $pdf->SetFillColor(51, 122, 183);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(255);
    $pdf->SetDrawColor(0,0,0);//$pdf->SetDrawColor(128,0,0);
    $pdf->SetLineWidth(.1);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',11);
    for($i=0;$i<count($header);$i++) {
        $pdf->Cell($header[$i]['width'],$row_ht,$header[$i]['name'],1,0,'C',true);
    }
    $pdf->Ln();

    // ROW  Color and font restoration
    $pdf->SetFillColor(224, 235, 255);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(0);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
    // Data
    $fill = false; $crt = 1; $lnt = count($boxes);

    foreach($get_pick_list AS $get_pick_list_data){
        $brdr = 'LR';
        if ($crt == $lnt) $brdr = 'LRB';


        $pdf->Cell($header[0]['width'],$row_ht,' '.$get_pick_list_data['date_received'],$brdr,0,'C',$fill);
        $pdf->Cell($header[1]['width'],$row_ht,' '.$get_pick_list_data['customer_name'],$brdr,0,'L',$fill);
  $pdf->Cell($header[2]['width'],$row_ht,' '.$get_pick_list_data['vendor_name'],$brdr,0,'L',$fill);
        $pdf->Cell($header[3]['width'],$row_ht,' '.$get_pick_list_data['item_description'],$brdr,0,'L',$fill);
        $pdf->Cell($header[4]['width'],$row_ht,' '.$get_pick_list_data['qty']   ,$brdr,0,'C',$fill);
        $pdf->Cell($header[5]['width'],$row_ht,' '.$get_pick_list_data['price'],$brdr,0,'R',$fill);
  $pdf->Cell($header[6]['width'],$row_ht,' '.$get_pick_list_data['shelf_no'],$brdr,0,'C',$fill);

        $pdf->Ln();
        $fill = !$fill;
        $crt +=1;
    }
    // Closing line
$pdf->Cell(250, 0, '', 'T');
    if ($isdebug==true){
        $path_to_pdf = 'assets/pdf/picklist.pdf';

        if (file_exists($path_to_pdf))  {   unlink($path_to_pdf); }
        $pdf->Output($path_to_pdf,'D');
        ob_end_flush();
    } else {
        $path_to_pdf = 'assets/pdf/picklist-'.'xx'.'.pdf';
        $pdfdoc = $pdf->Output($path_to_pdf, "F");
        ob_end_flush();
    }
    return array('status'=>1, 'msg'=>'');
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

-Eli

Answer (score -1):

You need to do `width 100%` and set `table-layout auto` also add CSS in coloum `white-space nowrap`

So add table style to follow

```
 table {
        table-layout: auto;
        width: 100%;
 }    
 table td {
       white-space: nowrap 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But where should I add the CSS?

Comment: you are using WriteHTML(http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script42.php) so in head part you can add ```<style>``` tag add your css there

Comment: Also you can write inline css

Comment: I am using CodeIgniter and there's no actual file so I'm not sure where to add the inline CSS. I'll add the code above in a bit.

Comment: Please try ```$pdf->MultiCell(75,7,’Insert your long string here’,1,’L’,false);```

The MultiCell basically allows for the printing of text with line breaks.

For param information please check http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm

Comment: Please check all param I think so it will work well for you there is some thing issue with parameter so please check link again for more details http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm

Comment: Neither FPDF nor the WrtieHTML method support CSS. So this answer is absolutely misleading and should be removed IMHO.